# Getting label feature with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

I need get the label text for each feature in a points layer.
I can read feature attribute using:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer_name')[0]
features = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest())
for f in features:
    attribute=f.['field_name']
```

but I need the label text (result of a expresion), it's diferent from attribute.

Comment: U mean u're labeling with an expression ?

Answer (score 7):

You can get the label text for each feature this way in QGIS 3:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

if layer.labelsEnabled():
    labeling = layer.labeling()
    palyr = labeling.settings()
    expression = QgsExpression(palyr.fieldName)

    context = QgsExpressionContext()
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(feature)
        expression.prepare(context)
        value = expression.evaluate(context)
        print(expression.formatPreviewString(value, True))
```